# UpdatePanel conditional mode issue when it has usercontrol inside it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

This is my markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updEml" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="+ Add Email" ID="lnkAddEmail" OnClick="lnkAddEmail_Click" />
            <div id="Emlpopup" style="width: 470px; display: none; height: 200px;">
                <uc:AddEditEmailAddress runat="server" ID="ucAdEdEml" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkAddEmail" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdEdEmail" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

As you can see my UpdateMode is set to Conditional. I want it to be refreshed when either lnkAddEmail or  btnAdEdEmail is clicked. But problem is btnAdEdEmail is inside my UserControl and so I am getting exception

> "A control with ID 'btnAdEdEmail' could not be found for the trigger
>   in UpdatePanel 'updEml'."

. How do I get around this issue?

Comment: You can try implementing custom EventHandler in your UserControl and update UpdatePanel trigger for new event: http://forums.asp.net/post/1980781.aspx

Answer (score 0):

By default, an UpdatePanel's ChildrenAsTriggers property is set to true. This means any control inside it that fires a post back will cause a refresh, so you don't need to specify any triggers.

Comment: That doesn't hold true. ChildrenAsTriggers is for immediate child control. My button is inside usercontrol.

Comment: Nope, it's for any descendant not just immediate child

Comment: Read this for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx

Comment: @TimTom That is when UpdatePanels are inside UpdatePanels, it's not to do with UserControls. A button inside a UserControl will trigger a refresh of the UpdatePanel